# Nuget Clean Package Remove/Install

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I'd like to remove an entire nuget package, and cleanly install it in my project again.

Sadly, for some reason it skips removing files that have been "modified", and then skips putting them in the project on reinstall, because they already exist.

Is there any flag i can set to unconditionally remove every single trace of a nuget package, alternatively overwrite all existing files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment, NuGet does not do what you want. During the uninstall process, NuGet will only delete content files if they have not been modified. And as you've noticed, the update process will not update files that were modified either.

The Uninstall-Package command does have a -Force option, but that is to "force" uninstall even if there are other packages that depend on this one.

We can certainly file this as an issue and perhaps incorporate it into a future version.

Another option would be to create a PowerShell script that will enumerate a package's contents, then allow you to delete all the content files. I'll see if there is a simple way to do this.

BTW: Perhaps you can figure out a better way to extend the existing content file other than modifying it directly. Especially since you're losing your changes when the package is updated.

Comment: I have this problem too. The thing is, I haven't actually modified any file content. All I've done is add the files to an svn repository. I guess whatever attributes SVN adds to the file are being interpreted as modifications as well.  This makes using nuget really inconvenient for anybody using a source control system.

Comment: Has this answer changed in the last 15 months?

Comment: So it looks like you can now force overwriting of the files on install as per the answer from @Simon_Weaver. But there is still no way to force an uninstall of the package to remove modified files if you no longer wish to use the package :( Could this get added to the NuGet feature list too?

Comment: If you're using Source Control, the following works fairly well. Uninstall the package using NuGet,  Delete all the files the package created on install, Reinstall the package, Merge your changes back into the files, Commit and continue!

Answer (score 6):

You can now do what you want! (finally)

You need to first update to the latest NuGet (I think this feature was added around April 2013). Do this by going to `Tools > Extensions and Updates` and click on `Updates` to update nuget.

Then the `-FileConflictAction` parameter will allow you to overwrite files.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation -Version 2.0.30506.0 -FileConflictAction Overwrite
```

([PowerShell Command Reference for Install-Package](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Install-Package))

Answer (score 3):

The NuGet Version 1.6 HAS a remove package function!
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-1.6

if the update of the extension fails (signatur missmatch), just uninstall and reinstall. this is a known problem.

Comment: Your cited page doesn't seem to refer to a 'remove package function'. Can you please explain what 'known problem' you're talking about and what aspect of v1.6 and later addresses that - right now your answer, while well-intentioned is very hard to divine useful info from

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened to me a few times. Go to the packages.config file that should be the root directory of your project and remove the insurgent (in your case the line with the package: SignalR). This will tell NuGet that the package was never installed.

Now you will be able to reinstall it through the repository, then uninstall it so everything is back to the way it was before you got into this mess. I am unsure how it is occurring.